# Bag tag information after name

Tags: air-travel, luggage, airports, airlines, airport-transfer

I traveled recently with SN Brussels Airlines. On my bag tag after my LAST NAME/GIVEN NAME (cut after 4 characters) then +011/12 on the way out and +011/19 on the way back. What does these numbers mean? The 12 and 19 roughly correspond to the bags weight in kgs, so it might be that. But the +011 I have no clue?

Comment: Did you happen to travel on the 12th and 19th of November?

Comment: Apparently it’s +01 then 1/12 or 1/19. Possible values are number of the passenger on a booking, number of the bag for a passenger, weight. There could be the check-in sequence number but that’s usual 3 digits.